# Adding lines between lines of the text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create this notepad design in full css.

[image]

Is it possible to put lines between texts lines ? I don't want underscore for the text though. For example It will be like this but without huge spacing between text and since whole text will be added by the user I cannot add span between lines.

```
Text Text Text Text Text Text 
_____________________________
Text Text Text Text Text Text
```

Comment: Either use a background image, or a foreground image with translucency, or take a look at the style options you have available, like borders for containers and the like. Often this is done using a bottom border on a span container which is wrapped. Endless possibilities.

Comment: Also https://css-tricks.com/fun-line-height/

Comment: If you don't need the extra line, and the one that is just on the paper. You could look into using Line Height (CSS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical approach for this is to use a bottom border for the span containing the actual text. The span container gets wrapped, which gives the desired look:

The markup:

```
<div id="notebook">        
    <span id="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
    </span>
</div>
```

The styling:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid darkgray;
}
span {
    border-bottom: 1px solid darkgray;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9tut5gy0/

Comment: It still doesn't look like a notepad. Lines look line underline... I wonder if I could be able to add background image to the textarea depending on the textsize chosen...

Comment: That was the other approach I mentioned in my comment above. Probably the best is to use an image one pixel wide and precisely as high as the lines are. The image has a single dot as a line at the bottom. When repetition for the background is set to repeated and indefinitely inside the container the effect should look exactly like lines on a notepad _and_ it should be easy to adapt to different line heights or containers.